# moderncv appends a vertical bar after name even if \title{} is not defined

Tags: moderncv

I'm using the following class:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}
```

I notice there is a vertical bar after the name like this: [image]

However, I checked the source code:

```
\namestyle{\@firstname~\@familyname}%
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@title}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\%
```

There shouldn't be a vertical bar if the title is not defined. What is wrong here?

Comment: Do you definitely not use `\title`?  Note `\title{}` still defines an empty title.